# JHIpster project with spring-boot-starter-graphql

Tags: jhipster

We are starting a JHipster based project, and we need to use graphql (spring-boot-starter-graphql). More concretely we are migrating a project that use spring-boot-starter-graphql dependency and we would like to integrate it into a jhipster project.
The pom include the dependency and is supposed to autoconfigure the graphql endpoint, but this never happend (nothing appears in the console and servlet is not responging), probably because of conflicts or missing configuration with in jhipster.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                                 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>involve.gbi.era4tb</groupId>
        <artifactId>era-4-tb</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <name>Era 4 Tb</name>
        <description>Description for era4tb</description>
    
        <repositories>
            <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-repository -->
        </repositories>
    
        <pluginRepositories>
            <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-plugin-repository -->
        </pluginRepositories>
    
        <!-- jhipster-needle-distribution-management -->
    
        <properties>
            <!-- Build properties -->
            <maven.version>3.2.5</maven.version>
            <java.version>14</java.version>
            <node.version>v16.17.0</node.version>
            <npm.version>8.19.1</npm.version>
    
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
            <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
            <start-class>involve.gbi.era4tb.Era4TbApp</start-class>
            <argLine>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx1G</argLine>
            <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
            <run.addResources>false</run.addResources>
            <!-- These remain empty unless the corresponding profile is active -->
            <profile.no-liquibase />
            <profile.api-docs />
            <profile.tls />
            <profile.e2e />
    
            <!-- Dependency versions -->
            <jhipster-dependencies.version>7.9.3</jhipster-dependencies.version>
            <!-- The spring-boot version should match the one managed by
            https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.jhipster/jhipster-dependencies/${jhipster-dependencies.version} -->
            <spring-boot.version>2.7.3</spring-boot.version>
            <!-- The hibernate version should match the one managed by
            https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/${spring-boot.version} -->
            <hibernate.version>5.6.10.Final</hibernate.version>
            <!-- The liquibase version should match the one managed by
            https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/${spring-boot.version} -->
            <liquibase.version>4.15.0</liquibase.version>
            <liquibase-hibernate5.version>4.15.0</liquibase-hibernate5.version>
            <validation-api.version>2.0.1.Final</validation-api.version>
            <jaxb-runtime.version>4.0.0</jaxb-runtime.version>
            <archunit-junit5.version>0.22.0</archunit-junit5.version>
            <mapstruct.version>1.5.2.Final</mapstruct.version>
            <!-- Plugin versions -->
            <maven-clean-plugin.version>3.2.0</maven-clean-plugin.version>
            <maven-site-plugin.version>3.12.1</maven-site-plugin.version>
            <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
            <maven-javadoc-plugin.version>3.4.1</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>
            <maven-eclipse-plugin.version>2.10</maven-eclipse-plugin.version>
            <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
            <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
            <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.2.2</maven-jar-plugin.version>
            <maven-idea-plugin.version>2.2.1</maven-idea-plugin.version>
            <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-resources-plugin.version>
            <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
            <maven-war-plugin.version>3.3.2</maven-war-plugin.version>
            <maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>3.1.2</maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>
            <checkstyle.version>10.3.2</checkstyle.version>
            <nohttp-checkstyle.version>0.0.10</nohttp-checkstyle.version>
            <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.12.1</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
            <checksum-maven-plugin.version>1.11</checksum-maven-plugin.version>
            <maven-antrun-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-antrun-plugin.version>
            <git-commit-id-plugin.version>5.0.0</git-commit-id-plugin.version>
            <modernizer-maven-plugin.version>2.4.0</modernizer-maven-plugin.version>
            <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.8</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
            <jib-maven-plugin.version>3.2.1</jib-maven-plugin.version>
            <jib-maven-plugin.image>eclipse-temurin:11-jre-focal</jib-maven-plugin.image>
            <jib-maven-plugin.architecture>amd64</jib-maven-plugin.architecture>
            <lifecycle-mapping.version>1.0.0</lifecycle-mapping.version>
            <properties-maven-plugin.version>1.1.0</properties-maven-plugin.version>
            <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.9.1.2184</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
    
            <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-property -->
        </properties>
    
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>tech.jhipster</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jhipster-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${jhipster-dependencies.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
                <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-add-dependency-management -->
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>tech.jhipster</groupId>
                <artifactId>jhipster-framework</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hppc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
                <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
                <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                <!-- Inherited version from Spring Boot can't be used because of regressions -->
                <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-loader-tools</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.tngtech.archunit</groupId>
                <artifactId>archunit-junit5-api</artifactId>
                <version>${archunit-junit5.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Adding the engine dependency to the surefire-plugin unfortunately does not work in the current version. -->
            <!-- https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_junit_5 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.tngtech.archunit</groupId>
                <artifactId>archunit-junit5-engine</artifactId>
                <version>${archunit-junit5.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
                <artifactId>problem-spring-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Spring Cloud -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
                <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
                <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-add-dependency -->
            <dependency> 
                <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId> 
                <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId> 
                <version>5.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency> 
                <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId> 
                <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId> 
                <version>5.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency> 
                <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId> 
                <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId> 
                <version>5.0.0</version> 
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
                <artifactId>graphql-java-extended-scalars</artifactId>
                <version>19.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.22</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
              <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
              <version>2.11.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

...

Can someone point to what would be happening?
Thanks in advance